# Unable to install packages on my Kali

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, kali-linux, centos-7

When I try to install a package or anything, I get the following error:

```
    Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package ____
```

Then I went into my Network Repository and input the following (from the official Kali Website):

1. Remove everything within that sources.list file
2. Went to the official Kali Website
3. Scroll down and look for "The kali-rolling repository"
4. Copy everything within that kali-rolling and paste on sources.list file
5. Save the sources.list file
6. Run the command: apt-get update

I am still unable to install any packages.
Please Help.

Comment: Try sudo apt-get update or sudo apt-get install {package}

Comment: Kali is absolutely not for beginners. Start on a more complete unix, switch to kali when you already know what you're doing. Compulsory kali link - [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: Did you (Author) try as suggested?  I have installed a couple of packages on Kali Full V2019.4 this way

Comment: @John Thanks for your suggestion! I tried it but it did not work. There was something wrong with my repository. I found a youtube video that helped lol.

Comment: This thread is 2 years old!    Try:  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove  .... Maybe just reinstall Kali.